# I am facing this error when running the camera-projector calibration script

Tags: python, camera, mapping, projection, camera-calibration

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "calibration_ChArucoWithCircles.py", line 255, in 
distCoeffs=distCoeffs)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.3) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'estimatePoseCharucoBoard'
Overload resolution failed:

- Required argument 'rvec' (pos 6) not found
- Required argument 'rvec' (pos 6) not found

Does anyone know how to solve this issue, thank you.

## Here is the script which cause the error:

```
pose, rvec, tvec = aruco.estimatePoseCharucoBoard(
                charucoCorners=charuco_corners, 
                charucoIds=charuco_ids, 
                board=CHARUCO_BOARD, 
                cameraMatrix=cameraMatrix, 
                distCoeffs=distCoeffs)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding two empty arrays at the end, one for the rotation matrix and one for the translation matrix:

```
pose, rvec, tvec = aruco.estimatePoseCharucoBoard(
    charuco_corners, 
    charuco_ids, 
    CHARUCO_BOARD, 
    cameraMatrix, 
    distCoeffs,
    np.empty(1),
    np.empty(1)
)
```

[Documentation](https://gregorkovalcik.github.io/opencv_contrib/d9/d6a/group__aruco.html#gaa6f144be4fe015e496374c1360eec555)

The two np.empty(1) arrays are needed in the case of Pose estimation without calibration data as a first estimation for rvec and tvec.

Comment: What should be the size of these arrays?

Comment: It doesn't matter. They are just as place holder for the two Output arrays. For some reason the translation from python to C++ needs them when parsing.